# booting an m.2 SSD (Intel 520) using m.2-to-PCIe adapter?

Tags: ssd, operating-systems, pci-express, m.2

so I have an Intel 520 m.2 card. It's my OS disk. I am currently using an m.2-to-SATA adapter so I can connect it to my Intel X58 motherboard.

I want to connect it an m.2-to-PCIe adapter so I can free up a SATA port for more storage (RAID).

This is the description for the m.2-to-PCIe adapter: "Adapter card support Socket2 (Gen2) B+M key PCIe x2 M.2 NGFF SSD and Socket3 (Gen3) M key PCIe x4 M.2 NGFF SSD to PCIe x4 "

Is what I want possible? Thanks.

pic of SSD: [[URL=""]https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOx6s.jpg[/URL]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOx6s.jpg)

pic of m.2-to-SATA adapter I'm curently using: [enter link description here](http://www.simplecom.com.au/ebay/170418_01.jpg)

pic of m.2-to-PCIe adapter: [[URL=""]https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9VF8.jpg[/URL]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9VF8.jpg)

Comment: Okay, so based on the picture, you have an [Intel SSD Pro 1500](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/ssd-pro-1500-series-m2-specification.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your SSD (Intel SSD Pro 1500, SSDSCKHF240A4L), is a SATA-only device. This is entirely within specs.

Because it “speaks” SATA, it can function with your current adapter.

Because it does not “speak” PCIe, it cannot function with a PCIe adapter.

Just buy an additional SATA controller. The basic ones are very affordable. I also recommend not using Intel RAID, I’ve had some bad (near-fatal) experiences with it.